# How to add permalink into WP_Query in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, permalinks, wordpress

I want to add Blog Page in front-page.php.I want to show only post title with link to actual post.I dont know where to put the_permalink in my code.My code like below:

```
 <div class="profile">               
                <?php 
                  $query = new WP_query( 'pagename=blog' ); 
                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ){
                    $query->the_post();
                    echo '<h2 class="text-center">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';                                
                       }
                     }
                  wp_reset_postdata();
                 ?>   
 </div><!--end blog-content -->
```

When I put ,the hyperlink goes to domain.com/get_permalink() not to actual url.

Example the actual url is domain.com/abc. 
When I click to the post title,it goes to domain.com/get_permalink()

Anyone can help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are using `get_permalink` in wrong way. Try following code.

```
<div class="profile">
  <?php
  $query = new WP_query( 'pagename=blog' );
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ){
      $query->the_post();
      echo '<h2 class="text-center"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
      the_title();
      echo '</a></h2>';
    }
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
</div><!--end blog-content -->
```

Comment: Thank you very much.may god bless you4ever. :D